# How can I add static DNS entry in Debian and block some sites?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dns

OK I'm admin noob.

Is there a way for adding static DNS entry?

I already tried to modify `/etc/hosts` file but without success.

Here is my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hitsu
127.0.1.1   www.deviantart.com
127.0.1.1   deviantart.com
127.0.1.1   www.youtube.com
127.0.1.1   youtube.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Eveyrything is fine, but when I enter for example
`adc.deviantart.com` I still get the page.

Is there a way to block that sites?

I am trying to increase productivity in work via disabling off-topic sites.

**EDIT**

Well I would like to block all sites from deviantart
something like

`127.0.0.1 *.deviantart.com`

Browser add-ons/extensions are a good solutions, but I use multiple browsers (chrome, opera etc) so it will be probably easier to block this in linux.

**EDIT #2**

There are some solutions for this problem eg
https://github.com/leftnode/get-shit-done

However it won't work for multidomains..

Comment: You could setup `dnsmasq` with some overrides, or configure a proxy like `squid` (in which you could even make non-productivity sites blocking time-dependent)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use wildcards in `/etc/hosts`. You will need to add every subhost separately.

Tell us more about the problem. Do you want to block traffic originating from your machine only, from the whole network? Only WWW traffic?

If you want to block all traffic to deviantart:

```
 host deviantart.com gives 199.15.160.100

 iptables -A OUTPUT -d 199.15.160.100 -j DROP
```

This will DROP all packages going to deviantart.com. This IP can change of course but you can check it periodically. If you want this to be persistent you would probably need to add this line to some /etc/rc.local script or appropriate for your distro.

Comment: I want to block specific traffic only for my machine.

Comment: So you can add all subdomains to /etc/hosts or use iptables like in my eidt

Comment: I don't know bash. Can I use Ruby or other dynamic languages at `/etc/rc.local` scripts? Do you other tools which can do the same job?

Comment: Nope. Just write there:
/usr/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -d 199.15.160.100 -j DROP

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is probably to use **dnsmasq**

Install `dnsmasq`

```
$ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

and add this line to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
address=/deviantart.com/127.0.0.1
```

This will block [deviantart.com](http://deviantart.com) and all its subdomains.

Note: For ubuntu see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150135/how-to-block-specific-domains-in-hosts-file/150180#150180).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `127.0.1.1 adc.deviantart.com` to `/etc/hosts` to block `adc.deviantart.com`.

But perhaps better way to boost productivity is to not visit `deviantart.com` voluntarily? You can also install [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) plugin for Firefox and use it to block these sites. Adblock lets you add pattern like `deviantart.com` and automatically block all subdomains - unlike `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added more info.